# How to send multiple acknowledgement to client using IHttpAsyncHandler in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0, activexobject, iasyncresult, ihttpasynchandler

I have implemented IHttpAsyncHandler in my class to perform 5-6 long running process in background and acknowledge to client on start of each task.

Earlier I was using one session variable and updating it with current status of task, and giving async call request to server from jquery in interval of 5 seconds to get current status, but this implementation is not good because its continually hitting request to server for status.

Then I implemented IHttpAsyncHandler in my application, now server itself send acknowledgement to client, but as per my implementation I am able to send only one acknowledgement! if I try to send more than one then its giving error as "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

please check my sample code.

**in my code 
ExecuteFirst() method works fine sending acknowledgement to client but ExecuteSecond() does not send acknowledgement its giving error.**

I goggled a lot but not getting proper way to send multiple acknowledgement to client.

this is my sample code, please help me if any one have any idea.

**Javascript**

```
function postRequest(url) {

        var url = 'StartLongRunningProcess.ashx?JOBCODE=18'

        var xmlhttp = getRequestObject();

        xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);


        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange =
                    function () {

                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                            var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
                            divResponse.innerHTML += "<p>" + response + "</p>";                             
                        }
                    }


        xmlhttp.send();

    }



 function getRequestObject() {
        var req;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest && !(window.ActiveXObject)) {
            try {
                req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch (e) {
                req = false;
            }
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
            }
            catch (e) {
                try {
                    req = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                }
                catch (e) {
                    req = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return req;
    }
```

**StartLongRunningProcess.ashx.cs**

```
public class StartLongRunningProcess: IHttpAsyncHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

            private AsyncRequestResult _asyncResult;
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {}

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true;}
    }


    public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
    {

        int32 jobCode= convert.ToInt32(context.Request["JOBCODE"]);
        _asyncResult = new AsyncRequestResult(context, cb, jobCode);

                  if(jobCode==18)
                  {

                   StartProcess18()

                  }
                  else
                  {

                   //StartProcessOther()

                  }
}



            private StartProcess18()
            {

                var task1= new Task(() =>
                {
                     ExecuteFirst();                           
                });


                var task2 = task1.ContinueWith((t1) =>
                {
                    ExecuteSecond();
                }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

                task1.Start();
            }



    private ExecuteFirst()
    {

          //notify to client that this job has been started
         _asyncResult.CurrentContext.Response.Write("First task has been started"); 
         _asyncResult.Notify();

         // Above line of code successfully send a acknowledgement to client 

         //Doing some long running process
    }


    private ExecuteSecond()
    {

          //notify to client that this job has been started
         _asyncResult.CurrentContext.Response.Write("Second task has been started"); 

          // Above line of code giving error and if I skip it and call Notify() this also does not work.

         _asyncResult.Notify();


         //Doing some long running process
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{

}


 }
```

**AsyncRequestResult.cs**

```
public class AsyncRequestResult : IAsyncResult 
{
    private HttpContext context;
    private AsyncCallback callback;     

    private ManualResetEvent completeEvent = null;
    private object data;
    private object objLock = new object();
    private bool isComplete = false;        

    public AsyncRequestResult(HttpContext ctx, AsyncCallback cb, object d)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        this.callback = cb;
        this.data = d;
    }

    public HttpContext Context
    {
        get { return this.context; }
    }

    public void Notify()
    {
        //isComplete = true;


        lock(objLock)
        {
            if(completeEvent != null)
            {
                completeEvent.Set();
            }
        }


        if (callback != null)
        {
            callback(this);
        }
    }


    public object AsyncState
    {
        get { return this.data; }
    }


    public bool CompletedSynchronously
    {
        get { return false; }
    }


    public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
    {
        get
        {
            lock(objLock)
            {
                if (completeEvent == null)
                    completeEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

                return completeEvent;
            }
        }
    }


    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get { return this.isComplete; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`HttpContext.Current` is not null only if you access it in a thread that handles incoming requests.

Your continuation task that is running is most likely running on a `ThreadPool` thread without the `HttpContext.Current` flowing to the continuation,  hence it being null.

Try setting your TaskScheduler to `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` in order to execute it in the same context.

```
        private StartProcess18()
        {

            var task1= new Task(() =>
            {
                 ExecuteFirst();                           
            });


            var task2 = task1.ContinueWith((t1) =>
            {
                ExecuteSecond();
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

            task1.Start();
        }
```

Comment: this is not working, when I add "TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()" in my code it is giving error.

Comment: Yes I will send you tomorrow, once I reach office

Comment: This is the error which I am getting "The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler"